# IE and Edge 503 file but can hit it directly

Tags: internet-explorer, microsoft-edge, http-status-code-503

I have some code that injects a script and style into the page. I keep getting 503 errors on the files but the request doesn't reach the server to return the 503.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out in my code that builds the script that it I was adding an extra colon to the domain with my url building. so the url looked like:

```
http://mydomain:/assets/js/index.js
```

The solution for IE and Rdge was that `window.location.port` returns an empty string if it is on port 80 and not to just append but check for port being null for other browsers and empty string for IE/Edge